# Using an interface to expose specific methods in a method chain

Tags: c#

```
namespace ScratchPad
{
    public class InterfaceTestBuilder : InterfaceTest1
    {
        public InterfaceTestBuilder Init()
        {

            return this;
        }

        public InterfaceTestBuilder Method1()
        {

            return this;
        }

        public InterfaceTestBuilder Method2()
        {

            return this;
        }

        public InterfaceTestBuilder Method3()
        {

            return this;
        }

    }

    public interface InterfaceTest1
    {
        InterfaceTestBuilder Init();
        InterfaceTestBuilder Method3();
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            InterfaceTest1 test = new InterfaceTestBuilder();

            test.Init();
                    test.Method3();
            test.Init().Method1().Method2().Method3();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Client class, my "test" instance is limited to just the Init() and Method3() methods, however when used in a method chain all methods are accessible. How can I use an Interface to limit what methods are accessible when I want my client to use a method chain?

I should also mention that there could be another Interface that only exposes another set of specific methods:

```
public interface InterfaceTest2
{
    InterfaceTestBuilder Init();
    InterfaceTestBuilder Method1();
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this before? AFAIK this is not possible. You can return different types that then can be chained together from the return type, but an interface is a public (or internal) visible contract

Comment: I have not seen this before, but I have already implemented a method chaining builder and was hoping an interface would be a cleaner implementation to expose methods based on some condition/scenario. I could use a different pattern by passing in my InterfaceTestBuilder to another class and through that class expose only the methods I want my caller to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method return types to `InterfaceTest1`

For example, change your interface to:

```
public interface InterfaceTest1
{
    InterfaceTest1 Init();
    InterfaceTest1 Method3();
}
```

Changing your `InterfaceTestBuilder` class implementation for the following methods:

```
public InterfaceTest1 Init()
{

    return this;
}
public InterfaceTest1 Method3()
{

    return this;
}
```

You will then not be able to make the following calls, as `Method1` will not be accessible after calling `Init`:

```
    InterfaceTest1 test = new InterfaceTestBuilder();

    test.Init().Method1().Method2().Method3();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there could be another Interface that exposes a different set of methods to my client.

Comment: @Nventex so change your question according to those mentions.